# Getting SQL Error "every derived table must have its own alias sql"

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I fix this query -

```
SELECT People.Name, Company.Name 
FROM People 
JOIN Company ON People.Current_Company_ID = Company.ID
WHERE Current_Company_ID IN
(SELECT Previous_Company_ID FROM People GROUP BY Previous_Company_ID HAVING Count(Previous_Company_ID) = (SELECT MAX(C) FROM (SELECT COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) AS C FROM People
GROUP BY Previous_Company_Id
ORDER BY COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) DESC)));
```

**`People Table`** has four columns

```
id, name, previous_company_name, current_company_name
```

**`Company Table`** has two columns

```
id, name
```

Comment: Format.. make it easy to show the problem to others.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    (SELECT COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) AS C 
FROM People GROUP BY Previous_Company_Id ORDER BY COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) DESC)
```

with

```
    (SELECT COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) AS C 
FROM People GROUP BY Previous_Company_Id ORDER BY COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) DESC) AA
```

You are missing an alias there.

You new query is:

```
SELECT People.Name, Company.Name 
FROM People JOIN Company ON People.Current_Company_ID = Company.ID WHERE Current_Company_ID IN (SELECT Previous_Company_ID 
        FROM People GROUP BY Previous_Company_ID HAVING Count(Previous_Company_ID) = (SELECT MAX(C) FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) AS C 
    FROM People GROUP BY Previous_Company_Id ORDER BY COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) 
    DESC
)AA
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

```
SELECT P.Name, C.Name 
FROM People AS P
JOIN Company AS C ON P.Current_Company_ID = C.ID
WHERE Current_Company_ID IN
(SELECT Previous_Company_ID FROM P 
GROUP BY Previous_Company_ID 
HAVING Count(Previous_Company_ID) = (SELECT COUNT(Previous_Company_Id) AS Cnt FROM P);
```